# Spark History Server not showing jobs from a different user

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have set up a YARN cluster (using `hadoop-3.3.0`) and configured spark (`spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2`) so that I can run my spark applications on YARN. All this set up has been done via `admin` user. `admin` user is present on each node of my cluster. To monitor the applications I have also started Spark History Server. The history server correctly shows spark applications submitted via `admin` user.
However if the spark job is submitted via a different user say `alice` the Spark History Server does not show applications submitted by `alice`. Is there any solution for this?

Setup details:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://<HDFS_URL>/spark-logs
spark.history.provider org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider
spark.history.fs.logDirectory hdfs://<HDFS_URL>/spark-logs
spark.history.fs.update.interval 10s
spark.history.ui.port 8080
spark.yarn.historyServer.address <HISTORY_SERVER_IP>:8080
```

`hdfs://<HDFS_URL>/spark-logs` has permission `777`

`$YARN_HOME/logs` has permission `777`

`$YARN_HOME/logs/userlogs` has permission `777`

Comment: Could you try to add the parameter "spark.ui.view.acls=admin" to the jobs submitted by `alice`? More on this parameter can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html).

Comment: I tried passing this parameter as you suggested but it did not show my application on the history server. I believe the parameter you mentioned is more related to spark UI itself which runs on port 404x and less related to spark history server